# SharePoint Error when I run PSConfig

Tags: powershell, configuration, cumulative-update

I am getting the following error when I attempt to manually run PSConfig following an update on this server from the June/July 2012 CU to the April 2013 CU (this is from the logfile):

```
06/10/2013 14:18:27  13  ERR            Task upgrade has failed with an unknown exception 
06/10/2013 14:18:27  13  ERR            Exception: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Cannot resolve the collation conflict between "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AI" and "Latin1_General_CI_AS_KS_WS" in the equal to operation.
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Run(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteNonQueryTds(String methodName, Boolean async)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(DbAsyncResult result, String methodName, Boolean sendToPipe)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SqlSession.ExecuteNonQuery(SqlCommand command)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Upgrade.SPStoredProcedureVerifier.AlterUserDefinedDatabaseFunction(String name, String content)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Upgrade.SPStoredProcedureVerifier.RefreshAll()
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Upgrade.SPContentDatabaseSequence.Upgrade()
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Upgrade.SPUpgradeSession.Upgrade(Object o, Boolean bRecurse)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPPersistedUpgradableObject.Upgrade(Boolean recursively)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPContentDatabase.Upgrade(Boolean recursively)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Upgrade.SPUpgradeSession.ReflexiveUpgrade(Object o, Boolean bRecurse)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Upgrade.SPUpgradeSession.Upgrade(Object o, Boolean bRecurse)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPPersistedUpgradableObject.Upgrade(Boolean recursively)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Upgrade.SPUpgradeSession.ReflexiveUpgrade(Object o, Boolean bRecurse)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Upgrade.SPUpgradeSession.Upgrade(Object o, Boolean bRecurse)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPPersistedUpgradableObject.Upgrade(Boolean recursively)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Upgrade.SPUpgradeSession.ReflexiveUpgrade(Object o, Boolean bRecurse)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Upgrade.SPUpgradeSession.Upgrade(Object o, Boolean bRecurse)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Upgrade.SPManager.InplaceUpgradeAdministrationWebApplication()
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.PostSetupConfiguration.UpgradeTask.Run()
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.PostSetupConfiguration.TaskThread.ExecuteTask()
```

Anyone have any idea on how to resolve this? I don't have direct access to my SQL instance, and anyway we are running both our single-server integration farm (which is what's failing here) and our 3-server pre-production farm off of this so I'm not sure I can just change the language settings for the entire server without throwing the other farm off.

I ran this command:

```
PSConfig.exe -cmd upgrade -inplace b2b -force -cmd applicationcontent -install -cmd installfeatures
```

...after confirming that my config DB did need to upgrade.

Comment: I'm currently troubleshooting this with MS support, so if anyone knows an answer, they have the opportunity to beat Microsoft at their own game!

Answer (score 1):

Well, the end result was that one of the content DBs on my farm had a different collation format than all the rest. Normally this wouldn't have been an issue - I'd just detach the DB, run the upgrade, and then re-attach it - but the DB in question was for my Central Admin web application. I had to basically remove and rebuild the entire farm, which was not fun, but the good news is that the issue is gone now.